# Playing Azure Media Services on Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, azure, video, media-streaming

I'm doing a proof of concept. The goal is to be able to stream videos from AMS on Sharepoint 2013.

I've been working with [this samples](http://ampdemo.azureedge.net/azuremediaplayer.html), with no luck.

On the *sharepoint side*, I've tried using all three code options that the shared link states (by inserting html code):

- Shared code
- Embed code
- Player code

I've also tried with the native "Insert Audio / Video" from sharepoint ribbon. None works. The only thing I manage to do so far is to play videos with the file directly (like point to a .mov or .mp4), but the objetive is to make a proof of concept with adaptive streaming.

The error I keep getting is:

[image]

Final comment, I've made some tests on O365, the results are similar:

[image]

Comment: Did you get any further with the POC.

Comment: Yes, apparently the problem was the way I was uploading the files (from a custom desktop app). Once I repeated the process directly from Azure Site, it was fixed.